# It is possible using 2 admob accounts with one app?

Tags: flutter, admob, ads

I have several flutter apps on Google Play and App Store. All the apps are linked to my Admob Account.
Recently a company asked me to put an AD from his AdMob account into my app.
Is it possible to do this by keeping also my ads (from my Admob Account) on my apps? I couldn't find any documentation about that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't really make sense to me. You don't put "an ad from an AdMob account into an app". AdMob serves ads from the service, and advertisers put the ads on the service.

It's weird that your company wants to put stuff into "your app".

Having said all that, it's unlikely you can tell an ad plugin to use different accounts at different times. Generally these get initialized at boot time and then left alone.